# get the iframe element in C#

Tags: c#, html, css

I'm trying to get the id of the second iframe which is iframe2 in the codebehind to add some css styling. This is my html:

```
 <body>
    <form id="Form1" method="post" runat="server">
        <table id="Table1">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <iframe id="iframe1">
                    </iframe>
                    <uc1 id="uc1"></uc1>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <asp:Panel id="Panel">
                    </asp:Panel>
                    <uc1 id="uc2">
                    </uc1>
                </td>

                <td>
                    <iframe id="iframe2">
                    </iframe>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
</body>
```

For some reason I'm not able to get the iframe id in C#. How can I do that please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Accessing the Iframe**

Ensure that you add the `runat="server"` attribute to the `<iframe>`:

```
<iframe id="iframe2" runat="server"></iframe>
```

This will enable to to access it in your code-behind via the `FindControl()` method:

```
// Access your iframe
var iframe = FindControl("iframe2");
iframe.Style.Add("border", "2px solid red");
```

Or directly by using its assigned `id`:

```
iframe2.Style.Add("border", "2px solid red");
```

**Regarding Styling**

You mention that you are explicitly trying to style this element. If that is the case, you should likely be using CSS as opposed to setting inline styles on the `<iframe>` element itself.

For instance, you could apply styles as such to target that element:

```
<style type='text/css'>
    #iframe {
        /* Place your styles here (i.e. border: 4px solid red, etc.) */
    }
</style>
```

It's worth noting that actually styling an `<iframe>` is going to only style the element itself, as the content that is rendered within it is essentially "sandboxed" within the element and won't be affected by some of the assigned styles.

Comment: for some reason when I added runat="server" I got 400 bad request error

Answer (score 0):

Change the IFrame to have runat="server" you can then get to it on the server side.

```
<iframe ID="MyIframe" src="" runat="server"></iframe>
```

You can set set items in C#.

```
MyIframe.Attributes["src"] = Page.ResolveClientUrl("~/ThisOtherPage.aspx");
MyIframe.Attributes.Add("style", "cursor:pointer;");
```